# Keep notebook running in cloud?

Tags: notebooks, wolfram-cloud

If I have a Wolfram Cloud account, is there some way to keep a notebook running when I'm offline, e.g. TMUX? Leaving long-running computations to keep running in the cloud when I close my laptop would be a really nice thing.

Comment: With Producer account you can set ScheduledTasks so you could set a single time task to evaluate notebook/script and it could create some kind of logs so you know at which stage it is later when you check on it.